# Using MCMC from PyMC as an efficient sampler for frequentist analysis?

Tags: python, pymc

Is there an easy way to use PyMC's MCMC algorithms to efficiently sample a parameter space for a frequentists analysis? I'm not interested in the point density (for Bayesian analysis), but rather want a fast and efficient way to sample a multidimensional parameter space, so I would like to trace all tested points (i.e. in particular also the rejected points), while recurring points need to be saved only once in the trace.

I would be grateful for any helpful comments.

Btw, thanks for developing PyMC, it is a great package!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom StepMethods to perform any kind of sampling you like. See the docs for how to create your own.